# Confluence server + ubuntu. Удаленный доступ

Tags: ubuntu, администрирование, confluence

Есть задача запустить сервер confluence на ubuntu. С первым и вторым сталкиваюсь первый раз. Установил confluence по инструкции с [оф.сайта](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/installing-confluence-on-linux-143556824.html).

Ввожу в браузере localhost:8090 - все работает отлично. Проблема в удаленном подключении к системе. Я настроил ddns(www.noip.com) на tp-link.

Пинг консоль показывает что идет, но ничего не происходит. Я думаю что я отправляю запрос на модем, а не на конкретную машину на которой стоит confluence.

Т.е. имеем: confluence + ubuntu. Необходимо введя с любого другого компьютера, не входящего даже в сеть с сервером, в строке браузера xxx.222.xxx.248 или xxx.222.xxx.248:8090 или xxx.222.xxx.248/index попасть именно в систему  confluence.

Comment: На роутере нужно настроить проброс порта на комп, где установлен confluence.

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий пользователя insolor помог решить проблему. Загуглив, решил все так:

1. Зашел в роутер TP-LINK TL-WR940N / TL-WR941ND
2. Переадресация -> Виртуальные серверы
3. Add new...
4. - Порт сервиса: 80
   - Внутренний порт: 8090
   - IP-адрес: 192.168.xx.xxx
   - Протокол: TCP
   - Стандартный порт сервиса: HTTP.

Ну плюс я еще настроил ddns.